# Integration vs sum over dense subsets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Why is the Lebesgue integral can't be written as an infinite sum of the form (or can it ?)

$$\int_0^1 f(t)dt= \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty {\lambda(f)}_i f(t_i)\quad , \ \forall f\in C([0,1])$$

where the $\{t_i\}$'s are some dense set in $[0,1]$ and the $({\lambda(f)}_i)$ is a sequence of scalars such that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |{\lambda(f)}_i|^2= 1$$

So you can't get a finite sum by taking them all to be zero and one to be the value of the integral as mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: If you look at the continuous functions only, then you know that their integral is equal to the limit of their Riemann sum. Then, can you write the limit of the Riemann sum as a term to the right ?

Comment: It looks like your scalars are allowed to depend on $f$, so you can do this with a finite sum even by just setting one scalar to be equal to the value of the integral and the rest to $0$.

Comment: the scalars depend on $f$ yes. @StatisticDean I am not sure I follow what you mean to do with the Riemann sum.

Comment: Never mind the Riemann sum. @user6247850's argument dooms the entire idea. (More precisely, you'd need to choose $\lambda_f(t_i)=I/f(t_i)$ for some $i$ (where $I$ is the value of the integral).

Comment: I am thinking the 'why' probably would come from considering a family of functions $\{f_n\}$, which we must construct.

Comment: @user6247850 thanks for the input, I read it but didn't get it yesterday. I added a condition on the $\lambda_f$'s, they are actually given by $f$ and do not depend on the $t_i$'s.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is the constant $1$.  What will your infinite sum be in that case?

Comment: the question is ill posed, how can I close it? or should I delete it at once?

Answer (score 0):

How about this [Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/calculus1/chapter/the-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals/):  If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then there exists $c \in [0,1]$ so that
$$
\int_0^1 f(t)\;dt = f(c) .
$$
So, the conjectured result is true where the sum has only one term, and the corresponding coefficient $\lambda$ is $1$.

If you insist on a dense set of points, let $\lambda(f)_i = 1$ for one term where $t_i = c$ and $\lambda(f)_i = 0$ for all others.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. Let $S = [0, 1] \setminus \{t_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$, and let $f = \chi_S$. Note that $S$ has measure 1, as the complement of a countable set. So $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$. But $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \lambda(f)_i f(t_i) = 0$.

Comment: Good answer.  Unfortunately, the OP is not very clear.  It does not say whether the points $t_i$ are allowed to depend on $f$.

Comment: @GEdgar The notation seems clear that the $\lambda(f)_i$s depend on $f$, while the $t_i$s do not.